# Application misconfiguration error for Azure Active directory

Tags: ionic3, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal

I am implementing Microsoft ADAL plugin in my ionic app 3, so for that i have created an account on Microsoft azure and register my app in Azure portal. After all necessary configuration i used the app credential in my ionic but it through configuration error.

Although i configured my app properly and Grant all necessary administrative permission. I searched this on all forum but error is there.

The error which popup

Thanks

AADSTS650056: Misconfigured application. This could be due to one of the following: The client has not listed any permissions for 'AAD Graph' in the requested permissions in the client's application registration. Or, The admin has not consented in the tenant. Or, Check the application identifier in the request to ensure it matches the configured client application identifier. Please contact your admin to fix the configuration or consent on behalf of the tenant. Client app ID:

Answer (score 5):

Based on the error message and your description, you may not grant admin consent to your tenant. After adding the permissions which need admin consent, you need click `Grant admin consent for tenant` button.

[image]

If you have already done this. Check if you are going to call AAD graph api, if yes, check if you have granted AAD graph permissions(not Microsoft Graph permissions). Also, remember to distinguish between application permission and delegated permission.

[image]

Comment: Hi,
I already added the Permission and grant Admin Consents to all permission and also Azure Active Directory Graph is selected. And also i assign both dedegated  and application permission which is necessary.

Comment: @MuhammadYaseen  Can you provide some more details about your configuration? Which api did you want to call and how did you call?

Comment: sorry @TonyJu i was busy with some other project and didn't solve that problem. Actually i am using Microsoft login on my Ionic 3 app.
Following are the steps

1) I created Microsoft azure account and create app on that and gave all necessary permission then i user app id in my ionic app but when login the it will return "Misconfigured Application".

Comment: let authContext: AuthenticationContext = this.msAdal.createAuthenticationContext('https://login.windows.net/common');

    authContext.acquireTokenAsync('https://graph.windows.net', '965fd668-31a1-4d45-a4c8-b14a37c395a6', 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient',null,null)
      .then((authResponse: AuthenticationResult) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(authResponse));
    

    })
    .catch((e: any) => alert(JSON.stringify(e)));

Comment: @MuhammadYaseen Have you configured your app multiple tenant?

Comment: i didn't get whet multiple tenant means?

Comment: @MuhammadYaseen You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant. Which account did you use to login? Azure AD user or just micrososft account?

Comment: for which login
Are you talking about the account which i used for login from my Ionic app or account which is used for registration of Microsoft Active Directory account?

Comment: Azure account is created by using simply outlook account